# Upgrading python from 2.7.1 to 2.7.3 using macports on OS X Lion breaks os.urandom

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion

I installed python 2.7.3 using macports on Mac OS Lion, and used `port select python python27`. However python version still shows 2.7.1 (although `which python` shows the correct macport installation directory i.e. `/opt/local/bin/python`). Moreover this causes python not to recognize `os.urandom` anymore.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.urandom
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urandom'
```

Any ideas why is that happening? And how to fix it?

Comment: Some clues here: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/977080 are you on a virtualenv?

Comment: Also, how are you running it? Are you sure you're not just running /usr/bin/python (which is a symlink to the built-in 2.7) instead of /opt/local/bin/python? If you're not sure, try starting python and looking at `sys.prefix`.